# Is there a way to mesh-warp downwards?

Tags: after-effects

What I want to do is, to animate a pressing of a perfume spray top. But since mesh warp only works in X and Y axes, I cannot do it in the traditional way.
So, is there a way to do that?

Comment: You need to explain what you're asking a bit better if you want good answers. A screenshot would help.

Comment: I want to simulate something like a button press; in this case, the perfume spray's button (I separated the button as a png file). I tried to do it with the mesh warp tool. But since the mesh warp allows us only to warp an object only on X and Y axes, I can't animate the squeeze with that tool. So, is there a way to do that task?

Comment: I can't understand why you can't just move the button down by animating its Y position.

Comment: No I don't want a 'button going down' movement. What I need is, a squeezing on the middle of the can's top.

Comment: You're still not explaining yourself very well. Why can't you just move the pins in the mesh downward?

Comment: Are you working in 2D or 3D?